# How to push object to an existing array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to figure out how to push a new object to an array in Go.

Screenshot of my DB:
[image]

I need to push a new object under `actors` array (where maximum size is 20 items in this array).

In Node.js I would have run `{ $push: { "actors": {$sort: {_id: 1}, $each: [{"name": "test"}], $slice: -20}} }`

But in Go I'm not sure what is the correct syntax for it.

This is how my collection struct is defined:

```
type General struct {
    ID              primitive.ObjectID  `bson:"_id"`
    general         string              `bson:"general,omitempty"`
    Actors []struct{
        ID          primitive.ObjectID  `bson:"_id"`
        name        string              `bson:"name,omitempty"`
    }
}
```

**** EDIT ****

Regrading the generation of an ObjectId:

I've updated my code according to your answer:

```
update := bson.D{{"$push", bson.D{{"actors", bson.D{{"$sort", bson.D{{"_id", 1}}}, {"$each", bson.A{bson.D{{"name", "test"}, {"_id", primitive.NewObjectId()}}}}, {"$slice", -20}}}}}}
```

But when I run the code then I get the following error: `undefined: primitive.NewObjectId (exit status 2)`

If I just run `fmt.Println(primitive.NewObjectID())` then I can see a new ObjectId is printed... so i'm trying to figure out why it is not working in the update query.

(I've imported `"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the [update document or pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#std-label-update-one-update) using the [bson primitives](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.0/bson#pkg-types) in "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson" package.

Generate a ObjectId with the [NewObjectID function in the primitive package](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.11.1/bson/primitive/objectid.go#L42).

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)
//...

update := bson.D{{"$push", bson.D{{"actors", bson.D{{"$sort", bson.D{{"_id", 1}}}, {"$each", bson.A{bson.D{{"name", "test"}, {"_id", primitive.NewObjectID()}}}}, {"$slice", -20}}}}}}
```

Then run the update pipeline against your collection.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

//...
filter := bson.D{{"_id", 12333}}
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)
```

Comment: Great that's seems to work well!
One more question, how do I create `_id` on default when inserting a new `actor`?
thx again

Comment: @YoniMayer Glad it worked out fine. I have updated my answer to include how to generate a new ObjectId for the actor.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  something is still not working correctly for me, and I get an error - I've updated my original question (please see EDIT part)

Comment: I had a typo in the function name. The function should be `NewObjectID` not `NewObjectId`